# check url change in webview android not work

Tags: java, android, url, webview

How check Url change into WebView

```
@Deprecated
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
{
    String url = view.getUrl();
    return true;    
}
```

This function only work on first time change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use for this issue `shouldInterceptRequest`

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {

return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);

}
```

It can be used for check all url change in webview

Comment: shouldInterceptRequest  is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you add `@Deprecated` annotation but as I know the old `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method indeed [deprecated in API level 24.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))

So if your `minSdkVersion` is 24 or above you can only use `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest)`, but using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` (like your code did) can just grab the **previous** URL if URL changed. if you want to grab the current URL after URL changed you can use `@JavascriptInterface`

First you should create a custom `WebViewClient`

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    // inject javascript method 'onUrlChange'
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.android.onUrlChange(window.location.href);");
    };

    // if your minSdkVersion is 24 you can only use this
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
    {
        String url = view.getUrl();
       // Log.d("LOG","previous_url: " + url);
        return false;
    }

    static class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void onUrlChange(String url) {
           // Log.d("LOG", "current_url: " + url);
        }
    }

}
```

I put both methods into it in case you want, and you can uncomment the `Log.d(...)` line to check the URL

In your MainActivity.java

```
...
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyWebViewClient.MyJavaScriptInterface(),
        "android");
mWebView.loadUrl(YOUR_TARGET_URL);
...
```

Don't forget putting `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` into `AndroidManifest.xml`